# Optimal way to convert an int into a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion

What is the best method (performance) to put an `int` into a `char` array?
This is my current code:

```
data[0] = length & 0xff;
data[1] = (length >> 8)  & 0xff;
data[2] = (length >> 16) & 0xff;
data[3] = (length >> 24) & 0xff;
```

`data` is a `char` array (shared ptr) and `length` is the `int`.

Comment: This is the best way. As far as I know. :)

Comment: An union can provide the same feature but be careful about endianness : http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Lowest execution time and CPU usage.

Comment: @Aybe: Actually, no, using a `union` in that way yields UB. Using a `union` for conversions is wrong.

Comment: @KacperFałat: It's just "optimal". You can't be "more" or "less" or "least" or "most" optimal ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you looking for memcpy

```
char x[20];
int a;
memcpy(&a,x,sizeof(int));
```

Your solution is also good as it is ***[endian safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)***.

**On a side note:-**

Although there is no such guarantee that `sizeof(int)==4` for any particular implementation.

Comment: Is memcpy endian safe ?

Comment: @KacperFałat:- Yes they are as it copies the values of num bytes from the location pointed by source directly to the memory block pointed by destination.

Comment: I have one more question, beacuse i readed that method is faster than manual copy, so is there option to return form char array int using memcpy like function ?
There is funcion returning that with my old API, return (unsigned int)(data[0]&0xff) | ((data[1]&0xff)<<8) | ((data[2]&0xff)<<16) | ((data[3]&0xff)<<24);

Comment: @KacperFałat:- I would suggest you to ask this as another question as that would help you also getting some good answers! :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use `reinterpret_cast`. Use the data array as if it were an int pointer.

```
    char data[sizeof(int)];
    *reinterpret_cast<int*>(data) = length;
```

BTW `memcpy` is much slower than this, because it copies byte by byte using a loop.
In the case of an integer, this will just be a straightforward assignment.

Comment: data has more values than 4.

Comment: Well. This fails on platforms where `sizeof(int) > 4`. You should make sure that it isn’t. Of course the same is true for OP’s code.

Comment: @KacperFałat it doesn't matter if data is larger than 4. It will reinterepert the pointer (beginning of array) as if it's an integer pointer. It would work with an offset as well, like Konrad said, it will just interpert the address as if it's the size of an int.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer Change the `4` to `sizeof(int)` then!

Comment: Might also have to make sure `data` has proper alignment (I have no idea how)

Comment: It should be `alignas(int) char data[sizeof(int)]`.

Comment: For at least GCC 4.9, the compiler views memcpy as a "builtin", and will inline calls to memcpy with the code you'd like.

Comment: This breaks strict aliasing rule, thus has UB.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way. Theoretically you could use `memcpy` or `reinterpret_cast` but you can't due to problems with [endians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Theoretically, and *practically*. The cast/copy way is absolutely safe as long as an endianness can be ensured (and it can be in many, though not all, applications).

Comment: But the need to change endian on most of platforms will give no performance boost in the case.

Comment: This is only relevant if you send the data to a different machine. As long as it stays on the same machine it’s safe and efficient. For many things that’s entirely sufficient. To claim that this way cannot be used is simply inaccurate.

Comment: Those darned endians.